# set syntax color to log files, .env.local files without detected extension

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

sometimes, vim don't color text because file haven't got extension or the right extension, like */var/log/syslog.1*, or *.env.local*

How to define color syntax temporarily or definitely ?

How to know which type is used by a file type … list *ftdetect* file… but in which folder is it located ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853028/how-to-force-vim-to-syntax-highlight-a-file-as-html/3853036#3853036
we can define it temporarily with command like :
`:set syntax=<syntax type>`,
for example for *syslog.1* file:
`:set syntax=messages`
I find *messages* type by running `cd /usr/share/nvim/runtime/syntax && grep -rn "Language:" | grep log`

other sample for *.env.local*:
`:set syntax=config` not the right type but I didn't find type file for .env
=> `:set syntax=sh` (thanks to @romainl)

Comment: `config` is the right filetype for `.env` files.

Comment: Setting the filetype is more likely what you want, and you can do that automatically with ftdetect scripts.

Comment: @romainl In my tests, I haven't got the same colors between my .env.local (with _config_) and my .env !

Comment: @bcag2 you are right, `.env` is assigned the `sh` filetype and syntax by default.